# How to create a detailed moon surface texture for close up shots?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, eevee-render-engine, procedural

I started working on my dream animation featuring the moon. So now I wanted to take a close up shot of the moon's surface but the problem is that the textures in the NASA website aren"t that detailed for close up shot , so how should I make a realistic one for closup ?

Let me elaborate , I am trying to make a realistic animation related to moon landing in 2024 , and I have 9 months of experience with blender . For example, I want to make a shot in which showing the Star-ship going in the orbit above the surface really close

**This Near**

This shot is rendered in EEVEE because the maps provided in the NASA's 3d moon kit are for distant view and are not for close up , and thats why cycles messes up the shadows if I crop the texture , so is there a procedural way I can create such renders by the way .

**You can even see the star-ship in this one**

In future there will also be scenes where I have shots on the surface itself
[image]

Comment: I guess in the animation, you may switch between cameras. For example you can make a long distance render with the current scene you have with camera 1 and for the close up shots you can create an entirely new plane with a much more detailed moon texture and make render the animation with camera 2. Later you can merge those two animations ? I am not sure whether I made myself clear...

Comment: yeah that will be a must here , but the problem is how to get those detailed close up textures for the surface , is procedural process a good option  , if yes can you help me do that

Comment: I guess you can create a procedural material. But I would better go for textures as I am no node expert... And about that texture, you can take a small piece of the existing texture onto the plae by unwrapping the plane and scaling it down in the UV editor ? But it comes at the cost of your texture resolution I guess. So that won't be ideal...

Comment: what do you think will be good , i think pictures of craters(closeup of specific parts of moon) on the NASA and others like ESA and ROSCOMOS and ISRO would be good?

Comment: Yes close up shots of a wide area of the surface of the moon might work. Ensure that u have a displacement map along with it or you won't get the required craters and detailes...You will get some extremely close textures of the surface of moon. U can use them but the problem is it will cause repeating textures since you will be forced to scale the UV map because of the size of the texture. You can get rid of that by the Uber mapping node from Blender Guru. By this method you can preserve the resolution of the texture.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

awnsere credits @Nxdhin2005 - Yes close up shots of a wide area of the surface of the moon might work. Ensure that u have a displacement map along with it or you won't get the required craters and detailes...You will get some extremely close textures of the surface of moon. U can use them but the problem is it will cause repeating textures since you will be forced to scale the UV map because of the size of the texture. You can get rid of that by the Uber mapping node from Blender Guru. By this method you can preserve the resolution of the texture.